Unable to open MUI Dialog from parent component in React
I am using React Typescript and MUI. I have a parent component with an 'Edit' button, when clicked , should display Dialog box with a form pre-populated with that specific data from the parents.Can use static data for the parent now, to display on the Dialog form.
I am unable to open the Dialog from the parent component.
Parents.tsx
interface Post {    
    id: number;
    name: string;
    email: string; 
  }
  
  export default function Parents()  {
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState<Post | null>(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);

    const handleClickOpen = () => {
        setOpen(true);
      };
    
      const handleClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
      };
  
  
  
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        <h1>Profile</h1>
        {error && <div>Error: {error}</div>} 
        {posts && (
        <div>                 
          <p>Name: {posts.name}</p>
          <Divider/>
          <p>Email: {posts.email}</p>
        </div>
      )}
     
      <button   onClick={handleClickOpen}>Edit</button> 
      <DialogBox/>
      </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );

  };

Dialog.tsx
export default function DialogBox(){
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
 
    const handleClickOpen = () => {
        setOpen(true);
      };
    
      const handleClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
      };

      
    return (
        <React.Fragment>        
        <Dialog
          open={open}
          onClose={handleClose}
          PaperProps={{
            component: 'form',
            onSubmit: (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
              event.preventDefault();
              const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
              const formJson = Object.fromEntries((formData as any).entries());
              const email = formJson.email;
              console.log(email);
              handleClose();
            },
          }}
        >
          <DialogTitle>Edit</DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>
            <DialogContentText>
             Edit Email address
            </DialogContentText>
            <TextField
              autoFocus
              required
              margin="dense"
              id="name"
              name="email"
              label="Email Address"
              type="email"
              fullWidth
              variant="standard"
            />
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
          <Button type="submit">Edit</Button>
            <Button onClick={handleClose}>Cancel</Button>
            
          </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>        
        </React.Fragment>
      );
}


How does the component DialogBox know when to open? You are not passing any state variables from its parent nor are you rendering it conditionally.

I am new to these, can you please help with code? It will be clearer.

To resume, you need to retrieve the "isOpen" parameter from the parent component.
To achieve this in React you have to use props. Have a look at the documentation
In your case, you can achieve this like so :
<DialogBox
   isOpen={open}
/>

Finally in your Dialog component, use the isOpen props passed from the parent component:
export default function DialogBox(props){
// const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

...

  
return (
    <React.Fragment>        
    <Dialog
      open={props.isOpen}
      ...
    >

